# How can I perform a ping or traceroute in python, accessing the output as it is produced?

Tags: python, ping, traceroute

Earlier, I asked this question:

[How can I perform a ping or traceroute using native python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151771/how-can-i-perform-a-ping-or-traceroute-using-native-python)

However because python is not running as root it doens't have the ability to open the raw ICMP sockets needed to perform the ping/traceroute in native python.

This brings me back to using the system's ping/traceroute shell commands.  This question has a couple examples using the `subprocess` module which seem to work well:

[Ping a site in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316866/ping-a-site-in-python)

I still have one more requirement though: I need to be able to access the output as it is produced (eg. for a long running traceroute.)

The examples above all run the shell command and then only give you access to the complete output once the command has completed.  Is there a way to access the command output as it is produced?

**Edit:** Based on Alex Martelli's answer, here's what worked:

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn('ping -c 5 www.google.com')

while 1:
        line = child.readline()
        if not line: break
        print line,
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) is what I'd reach for, "by default", for any requirement such as yours -- there are other similar modules, but pexpect is almost invariably the richest, most stable, and most mature one.  The one case where I'd bother looking for alternatives would be if I had to run correctly under Windows too (where ping and traceroute may have their own problems anyway) -- let us know if that's the case for you, and we'll see what can be arranged!-)

Comment: This will only run on linux so using pexpect shouldn't be a problem. I'm checking it out now.

Comment: On Linux (and all other unixoid systems I've tried, inc. MacOSX;-), pexpect works a charm -- let us know if you're having any problems with it, because I'm sure they can be excellently well solved!-)

Comment: Wow, pexpect worked flawlessly and easily (and can do a bunch more stuff).

Answer (score 5):

You should read the documentation for the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module, it describes how to run an external process and access its output in real time.

Basically, you do

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['tracert', host], stdout=PIPE)
while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    # Do stuff with line
```

Actually, the answers in the SO question you linked to are very close to what you need. [Corey Goldberg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316866/ping-a-site-in-python/318142#318142) uses a pipe and `readline`, but since it runs ping with `-n 1` it doesn't last long enough to make a difference.

Comment: Pipes are buffered (not line-buffered) by default. Unless your traceroute does setvbuf() or similar you will not get the output as it is produced. See my answer.

Comment: On the system in question, traceroute is line-buffered and ping is not so this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a tty pair for the subprocess and run inside of that. According to the C standard (C99 7.19.3) the only time stdout is line buffered (as opposed to fully buffered which is what you say you don't want) is when it's a terminal. (or the child called setvbuf() obviously).

Check out os.openpty().

Untested code:

```
master, slave = os.openpty()
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    os.close(master)
    os.dup2(slave, 0)
    os.dup2(slave, 1)
    os.dup2(slave, 2)
    os.execv("/usr/sbin/traceroute", ("traceroute","4.2.2.1"))
    # FIXME: log error somewhere
    os.exit(1)
os.close(slave)
while True:
    d = os.read(master)
    if len(d) == 0:
        break
    print d
os.waitpid(pid, 0)
```

Note that having the child process (just after fork()) call setvbuf() will **not** work, since setvbuf() is a libc function and not a syscall. It just changes the state of the current process output, which will be overwritten on the exec call when the new binary in loaded.

Comment: This is really cool, so +1, but Popen worked fine for me on Ubuntu and on XP. No problem with buffering.

Comment: Then I'd say that your traceroute program uses setvbuf() or fflush(). But keep this in mind when running other stuff thay may not use them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

```
# const_output.py
import sys
from subprocess import Popen

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print 'Usage: const_output.py "command to watch"'
    sys.exit(1)

cmd_line = sys.argv[1:]

p = Popen(cmd_line)
p.communicate()[0]
```

Example usage:

traceroute:

```
> python const_output.py traceroute 10.0.0.38
traceroute to 10.0.0.38 (10.0.0.38), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.0.0.38 (10.0.0.38)  0.106 ms  0.023 ms  0.021 ms
```

ping:

```
> python const_output.py ping 10.0.0.38
PING 10.0.0.38 (10.0.0.38) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.38: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.38: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.075 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.38: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.076 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.38: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.073 ms
```

top:

```
> python const_output.py top
   # you will see the top output
```