# How to send arguement or instruction from web to linux machine and displaying result in web?

Tags: linux, bash, networking, web-applications

The main idea is i am going to implement, i think so it's quite new.Main idea is here i want to do traceroute scan from web.Suppose i request for traceroute instruction or by passing parameter from web and parameter passing to linux server should be executed and the result should be returned to the website.

Actually i been through the series of instruction regarding the CGI script and some of passing the parameter to linux machine.I have tried some of bash intstruction using REST feature but i am not getting any near to it.For example i have gone through these traceroute link

> http://ping.eu/traceroute/
>   and i am not able to understand the mechanism how it works.

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble, but this idea is [very far from new](https://www.google.com/search?q=online+traceroute).

Comment: you can execute the traceroute command on your linux box and get the results back to your web application. you can execute system commands from php,python etc. this is  a good link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151897/how-can-i-perform-a-ping-or-traceroute-in-python-accessing-the-output-as-it-is

Comment: Actually the link is quite complex for me to understand the main concept is here that i have website xyz.com and i have designed a box to input the website name and after the sending the query it should redirect to linux machine where traceroute is installed and when the command is executed in machine the outpout should be displayed in my website.so please help me in understanding the logic.

Comment: actually you can execute remote commands from one server to anohter.using ssh.

Comment: Ya i have run the remote command from ssh, ssh takes time and authentication and lots of issue but the scenario is here as i have mentioned previously.I want to implement the feature of http://ping.eu/traceroute/  in my website...

Answer (score 0):

You can search about [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). This is what is used in [travis-ci.org](https://travis-ci.org/) to display the console.

I have never used this feature but I am very interrested in having some documentations or tutorials, so if you find something please let me know.