# Simple ping implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, ping

I need simple ping that will return some float number or None if destination unreachable. I am using Python 3 and windows and don't want to use standart ping, cause i have to decode bytes from shell and parse results. I know nothing about implementation of ICMP protocol so ready to use library is the best choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a pure Python implementation like the following:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ping

or if you prefer this one:

http://www.python.org/~jeremy/python.html

and also take a look here, because they are discussing about the subject and you may find it useful:

[python non-privileged ICMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189389/python-non-privileged-icmp)

**UPDATE**

Without the need of patching for Py 3, a very simple example:

https://github.com/volftomas/pyicmp

Comment: First says that code is for python 2, the second says that code was written for python 1.4.

Comment: @m9_psy Yes, I know that but they can be modified to work with 3.x. I'm unaware of any implementation in 3.x, but it should serve as an example of how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

[Active State Recipes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/) is always the first place when I want to find such tiny/common/useful code snippets.

Here's one:

[icmplib (Python recipe)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576662-icmplib/)

It works in Python3,

Comment: It is what i need, but it does not work on windows cause of os.setuid

Comment: @m9_psy Have you tried the example from the update from my answer?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be working well